# MongoDB: query into two attributes of a nested field

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume I have the following document in MongoDB:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  title: 'Pulp Fiction',
  year: 1994,
  score: 94,
  director: {
    last: 'Tarantino',
    first: 'Quentin'
  },
  actors: [
    {
      last: 'Travolta',
      first: 'John'
    },
    {
      last: 'Thurman',
      first: 'Uma'
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I write a query such that this document is returned with a query for director first name ***and*** director last name?

I tried the following (which failed):

`>> db.movies.find( { "director": {"last": "Tarantino"}, {"first": "Quentin"} })`

Then, I tried the following (which works, but is probably not the most idiomatic way):

`>> db.movies.find( {$and: [ {"director.last": "Tarantino"}, {"director.first": "Quentin"}]} )`

Is there a simple, idiomatic way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options, but for nested fields in a document, I find this way the easiest using [`find`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document) - it's like a copy/paste from the original document in the database.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "director": {
    last: "Tarantino",
    first: "Quentin"
  }
})
```

Try it on [monoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mi-mlkOl-6U).

If I need a stage in an aggregation pipeline, it's almost the same - it's just adding the proper [`"$match"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) syntax for a stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "director": {
      last: "Tarantino",
      first: "Quentin"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zp3sZfirLez).